# What are "many successive interrupted connection requests" in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I regularly have the following error:

*PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1129] Host 'MY SERVER' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'*

It is easy to solve the problem with a regular (like crontab) *mysqladmin flush-hosts* command or increasing the max_connect_errors system variable, as written [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blocked-host.html).

BUT ! What are "**many successive interrupted connection requests**", why is this happening?

I'd rather prevent the problem upstream, rather than correcting blocking.

MySQL version : 5.5.12. I'm using Zend Framework 1.11.10 and Doctrine 2.1.6.

There are no mysql_close() nor mysqli_close() in my PHP Code.

max_connect_errors has the default value, 10, and I don't want to increase it yet, I want to understand why I've got the errors. I use a cron, every 5 minutes which does a mysqladmin flush-hosts command.

Comment: PHP version? MySQL version? Server configuration? This may depend on too many factors.

Comment: That means you're killing connections half-way through. Are you .close()-ing your db connections ?

Comment: what is the value of  max_connect_errors ? You need to provide us details and the changes you made to resolve it. Then only we can help.

Comment: There are no mysql_close() nor mysqli_close() in my PHP Code.

I'm using Zend Framework 1.11.10 and Doctrine 2.1.6.

max_connect_errors has the default value, 10, and I don't want to increase it yet, I want to understand why I've got the errors.

I use a cron, every 5 minutes which does a mysqladmin flush-hosts command.

Comment: @Alatar If you're using PDO, there *shouldn't* be any `mysql_close()` or `mysqli_close()` calls anywhere - they are functions that belong to different extensions. With PDO [`To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) - so you shouldn't need to do it explicitly. Are PHP/MySQL on the same server?

Comment: I've got 3 PHP servers which are connecting to only 1 MySQL server. I'll read the way PDO work.

Answer (score 1):

This response is by design as a security measure, and is the result of reaching the **max_connection_errors** value for mysql.  [Here's a link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/communication-errors.html) Oracle provides which details most of the possible causes and solutions.

Ultimately this means that there are so many successive connection failures that MySql stops responding to connection attempts.

> I use a cron, every 5 minutes which does a mysqladmin flush-hosts
>   command.

As you are reaching this limit so quickly, there are only a few likely culprits:

1. Server is not correctly configured to use PDO.
2. Running code includes very frequently creating new connections.

   - Results in quickly reaching the **max_connections** value, causing all subsequent connection attempts to fail... thus quickly reaching the **max_connection_errors** limit.
3. Code is hitting an infinite loop, or cascading failure.

   - Obvious possibility, but must be mentioned.
   - (i.e: pageA calls pageB and pageC, and pageC calls PageA)
4. PDO is running fine, but some scripts take a long time to run, or never end.

   - Easiest way to catch this is turn down the **max_execution_time**.

It is likely that whatever the case, this will be difficult to track down.

1. Log a stack-trace of every mysql connection attempt to find what code is causing this.
2. Check the mysql.err logfile

While PDO does not require explicitly closing mysql connections, for cases like this there's a few practices that can prevent such ServerAdmin hunts.

- Always explicitly close mysql connections.

  - Build a [simple Class](http://edrackham.com/php/simple-php-mysql-class/) to handle all connections. Open, return array, close.
  - The only time you need to keep a connection open is for cursors.
- Always define connection arguments in one and only one file included everywhere it is needed.
- Never increase **max_execution_time** unless you know you need it and you know the server can handle it. **IF** you need it, explicitly increase the value only for the script that needs it. *php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php*

  - If you increase **max_execution_time**, increase **max_connections**.

dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Answer (score 0):

It means that mysqld has received many connection requests from the given host that were interrupted in the middle. Check out this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blocked-host.html) from the documentation for more info.